# Can't get SparkR session to come up in Windows 7 (Java timeout error)

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have Spark installed, Java install, paths correctly set. And, yet, it does not work and gives me a Java timeout error.

Has anyone gotten this to work? What am I missing?

```
Sys.getenv('SPARK_HOME')
[1] "C:/Program Files/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7"

Sys.getenv('JAVA_HOME')
[1] "C:\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_74"

.libPaths()
[1] "C:/Program Files/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/R/lib"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.3.1/library"              

library(SparkR)

Attaching package: ‘SparkR’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    cov, filter, lag, na.omit, predict, sd, var, window

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    as.data.frame, colnames, colnames<-, drop, endsWith, intersect, rank,
    rbind, sample, startsWith, subset, summary, transform, union

sparkR.session(master = 'local')
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: C:/Program Files/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
Launching java with spark-submit command C:/Program Files/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit2.cmd   sparkr-shell C:\Users\BLAHUSER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiGe4EB\backend_port11587c2522e 
Error in sparkR.sparkContext(master, appName, sparkHome, sparkConfigMap,  : 
  JVM is not ready after 10 seconds
```

**UPDATE / EDIT:**

I finally managed to get Spark and sparkR.session() to work AFTER doing the following:

1) Moving the Spark installation from 'Program Files' folder to the top level drive folder (apparently the spaces in folder names, which Windows uses are a problem).

2) Installing winutils.exe in C:\winutils\bin.

3) Setting HADOOP_HOME to 'C:\winutils\'.

4) Adding C:\winutils\bin to the path and also the Spark bin to the path.

However, now I can't create a data frame in Spark. Get this error. Any thoughts?

```
> sparkR.session(master = 'local[*]')
Spark package found in SPARK_HOME: C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7
Launching java with spark-submit command C:\spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit2.cmd   sparkr-shell C:\Users\TUMULU~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpiyYUM7\backend_port1b302ee5515 
Java ref type org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession id 1 
> 
> df <- as.DataFrame(faithful)
Error in invokeJava(isStatic = TRUE, className, methodName, ...) : 
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.IsolatedClientLoader.createClient(IsolatedClientLoader.scala:258)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveUtils$.newClientForMetadata(HiveUtils.scala:263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:39)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.metadataHive(HiveSharedState.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedState.externalCatalog$lzycompute(HiveSharedState.scala:46)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSharedSt
```

Comment: It does not work from raw R console either. Same error.

Comment: Does it work from command prompt?

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Can anybody please help??